# Sql server : select members having 2 or more records on different date of same class

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find out all the member ids who have more than 2 records on a different dates in the same class.

```
+----------+------------+-------+-----------+
| MemberId |    Date    | Class |           |
+----------+------------+-------+-----------+
|   118111 | 2/18/2020  | A     | Valid     |
|   118111 | 10/15/2020 | A     | Valid     |
|   118216 | 1/31/2020  | B     | Valid     |
|   118216 | 5/16/1981  | B     | Valid     |
|   118291 | 6/9/2020   | A     | Valid     |
|   118291 | 12/5/2020  | A     | Valid     |
|   118533 | 4/9/2020   | A     | Not valid |
|   118533 | 11/11/2020 | B     | Not valid |
|   118533 | 7/22/2020  | C     | Valid     |
|   118533 | 10/25/2020 | C     | Valid     |
|   118293 | 3/30/2020  | A     | Not valid |
|   118293 | 3/30/2020  | A     | Not valid |
|   118499 | 4/16/2020  | B     | Valid     |
|   118499 | 7/26/2020  | B     | Valid     |
|   118499 | 3/25/2020  | A     | Not valid |
+----------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

I have made a query which checks only 2 records but unable to find a solution for checking more than 2 records.

```sql
select mc.* 
    FROM table1 AS mc
    JOIN table1 AS ma ON ma.memberid = mc.memberid
        AND ma.date != mc.date
        AND ma.class = mc.class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming* you just want the `memberid` you can us a `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT memberid
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY memberid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Date]) > 2;
```

Comment: But I need to check the class as well.

Comment: Add `Class` to the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` @AnantGupta ? You don't tell us what the expected results are so I took a little guess.